# How to add a user control inside a tabbed page in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: User control issue]

I need a page to be designed as in the picture. Image inside the read ellipse is a user control created using of a `ContentView` I need a tabbed view where I can actually swipe through the content pages so I used a `TabbedPage` for this purpose. how can I place the user control which is common to all `<TabbedPage.Children>` inside the `TabbedPage`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:TestApp.View.UserControls;assembly=TestApp"
             xmlns:TabControl="clr-namespace:TestApp.View;assembly=TestApp"
             x:Class="TestApp.View.TestView"
             >

   <!--Not working even if I place this on a grid -->
   <!--<userControls:ElectionTimer  EndDate="{Binding ELDate}"/>-->

 <TabbedPage.Children>    
    <TabControl:AllView Title="All"/>
    <TabControl:EducationView Title="Education"/>
    <TabControl:HealthView Title="Health"/>
   </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't. You'll have to create a `CustomRenderer` or use `CarouselView`.